# Final Issue in TicTacToe

Tags: python

This is my code for reference:

```
import math
def tic_tac_toe():
    board1 = []
    end = False

def choose(): 
   global num
   num = input("How large do you want the grid? (input the SIDE length)")
   for a in range(num**2):
       board1.append(a)

def draw():
    x = num
    v = 0
    for a in range(x):
        print 
        for b in range(x):
            print(board1[v]),
            v = v + 1
    size = num
    rows = [tuple(range(i * size, (i + 1) * size)) for i in range(size)]
    cols = [tuple(range(i, size ** 2 * 1, size)) for i in range(size)]
    diags = [tuple(i * (size + 1) for i in range(size)), tuple(i * (size - 1) for i in range(1, size + 1))]
    global howtowin
    howtowin = tuple(rows + cols + diags)

def p1():
    n = choose_number()
    if board1[n] == 'X' or board1[n] == 'O':
        print("\nAre you stupid... Try again")
        p1()
    else:
        board1[n] = 'X'

def p2():
    n = choose_number()
    if board1[n] == 'X' or board1[n] == 'O':
        print("\nAre you stupid... Try again")
        p2()
    else:
        board1[n] = 'O'

def choose_number():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input())
            if a in board1:
                return a
            else:
                print("\nCan you not count to " + str(num**2) + "? Try again")
        except ValueError:
           print("\nI don't speak French! Try again")

def check_board():
    count = 0
    for a in howtowin:
        if board1[a[0]] == board1[a[1]] == board1[a[2]] == 'X':     #check all lengths 3-...
            print("\nPlayer 1 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
        if board1[a[0]] == board1[a[1]] == board1[a[2]] == 'O':
            print("\nPlayer 2 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
    for a in range(num*num):
        if board1[a] == 'X' or board1[a] == 'O':
            count += 1
        if count == num*num:
            print("The game ends in a Tie\n")
            return True

choose()
while not end:
    draw()
    end = check_board()
    if end == True:
        break
    print("\n\nPlayer 1 choose where to place a 'X'")
    p1()
    print
    draw()
    end = check_board()
    if end == True:
        break
    print("\n\nPlayer 2 choose where to place a 'O'")
    p2()
    print

if raw_input("Play again (y/n)\n") == 'y':                                  
    print
    tic_tac_toe()
else:
    print("\nThanks for playing!!!!!!")

tic_tac_toe()
```

My issue is check_board(); I hard-coded it for a side value of 3. I now need it to work for any side length value.

Comment: How about using `all`. Like - `if all([board1[a[i]] == 'X' for i in range(board_size)])`

Comment: you havent defined `board1` before you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found pretty elegant, using `all` and `any`:

```
def is_winning_row(board, size, player):
    return any((all(board[i][j]==player for j in range(size))) for i in range(size))
```

This function will return `True` if there is a row winning for `player` on `board`, `False` else.

From this, you probably can find how to do this with the columns, and then with the diagonals.

If you do not want to have to pass `size` to the function, just replace `size` inside the body by `len(board)` (which will work as long as `board` is a square).

Comment: `any(all(cell == player for cell in row) for row in board)`

Comment: @PeterWood Works as well, but I cannot see a way to perform the same on columns, and I wanted the solution to be symmetrical. But yours is surely better, in general.

Comment: I see, yes, you can do more, more easily, by using indexing.

Comment: @PeterWood Which is frustrating, because iteration is nice :)